# int to hex conversion not going proper for high values 225943 is being converted into 0x000372ffffff97

Tags: c, hex

My C program takes a random int high value and convert it into hex and write it to a file. Everything goes well if the value is 225919 or less 
eg. 225875 is `00  03  72  53`
*but* if the value is above 225919 it starts writing extra `ffffff` for last byte in the hex value example 885943 is `00 03 72 ffffff97`, while the right value would have been `00 03 72 97`.

Code that writes the value into file is as follows:

```
char *temp = NULL;
int cze = 225943;
temp = (char *)(&cze);
for (ii = 3; ii >= 0; ii--) {
    printf(" %02x ", temp[ii]);  //just for printing the values
    fprintf(in, "%02x", temp[ii]);
}
```

Output is: `00 03 72 ffffff97`

Expected output: `00  03  72  97`

Please help, any pointer is appreciated.

Comment: Just as a matter of style, defining `temp` with the value `NULL` then (almost) immediately assigning it a new value is a waste of time. Just define it where it's first given a meaningful value: `char *temp = (char*)&cze;`.

Answer (score 5):

Your `temp` array contains `char` values, which in most cases means `signed char`.  The values are then being printed as signed `char`s, so any byte greater than `0x7f` is considered a negative value.  When that value is passed to `printf`, it is implicitly converted to `int`.  This adds one or more bytes containing all `1` bits if the number is negative.

Change the datatype to `unsigned char`.  This will cause the implicit promotion to change to `unsigned int` and you'll get the correct values.

```
unsigned char *temp=NULL;
int cze=225943;
temp=(unsigned char *)(&cze);
for(ii=3;ii>=0;ii--){
    printf(" %02x ",temp[ii] );//just for printing the values
    fprintf(in,"%02x",temp[ii]);
}
```

Alternately, you can use the `hh` length modifier in `printf`, which tells it that the argument is a `char` or `unsigned char`.  This will restrict it to printing 1 byte's worth of data.

```
printf(" %02hhx ",temp[ii] );
```

Comment: *"This adds one or more bytes containing all 1 bits if the number is negative."* - AKA sign extension